# Why does wireshark know using http protocol dissect messages from non-standard http port?

Tags: http, wireshark, mesos, wireshark-dissector

I use `tcpdump` to capture the messages between `Mesos` master and client, and use `wireshark` to open it:
[image]

Why does `wireshark` know using `http` protocol to dissect the message though the port is `5050`, not `80`. I don't set any special configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does wireshark know using http protocol to dissect the message though the port is 5050, not 80.

Because, in the version of Wireshark you're using, there's a "heuristic" version of the HTTP dissector, which is called for any TCP segment that hasn't been dissected by other dissectors; it looks at the packet to see if it looks enough like part of an HTTP request or response and, if it does, dissects it.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not too specific, but from what I could understand you want to know how Wireshark dissects messages from other ports. Because Wireshark scans all ports